Do mesh routers (Eero Pro 6e) have omnidirectional radio waves?
I have a number of Eero Pro 6e routers, placed in a variety of locations around my house. However, I want to use any advantage I can, to “direct” the signal as much as possible.
My question is, does Eero Pro 6e routers broadcast omnidirectionally, or are there faces of the router which are “quieter” or “louder”?

Some mesh routers have Omnidirectional radios some do not. Your question about quieter and louder faces doesn’t make sense in the context of a WiFi receiver.

@Ramhound: As far as I know, transmit and receive are mostly symmetric – e.g. if an antenna is designed to transmit in a specific direction then it is mostly sensitive in that direction, and vice versa...

@grawity - In my experience the vast majority of wireless routers have external antennas

According to this ad on Amazon, "eero’s patented TrueMesh technology intelligently routes traffic to reduce drop-offs and dead spots."
Most modern WiFi routers have multiple antennas, whether internal or external, and can switch amongst them to improve signal strength and quality, such as this description from Adant: "Adant’s Smart Antenna Technology... electrically reconfigures the beam’s pattern and polarization... that in a few milliseconds selects the optimal antenna radiation... for maximum wireless performance." Therefore, the router is automatically configuring itself. Anything you do to try to redirect the signal would be negated by the internal software.
The best you can do is to mount all units in the optimal place, clear of large metallic objects (e.g., poly/aluminum covered insulation in a wall), and away from devices that might cause interference, such as microwave ovens and other electrical devices.
You might try using an app that rapidly reports the WiFi signal quality and strength, such as Nirsof't WiFiInfoView for Windows, or WaveMon for Linux, for a numeric comparison as you move routers or PC's.

For a regular consumer product, if it's not mentioned otherwise then it's safe to assume that they're omnidirectional at least horizontally (and I suppose that Wi-Fi beamforming more than compensates for any minor differences).
Some manufacturers publish the "radiation pattern" diagrams; it doesn't look like Eero does, but they do say that

eeros radiate their signal more upwards than downwards, but mostly along the plane they’re placed on.

